# How to access a member of nested structure using pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
 struct date
 {
        struct time
        {
               int sec;
               int min;
               int hrs;
         };
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
  };
int main(void)
{
     stuct date d,*dp=NULL;
     dp=&d;
}
```

Now using structure pointer dp I want to access member of structure time sec.How do I do it?

Comment: Did you intend to have a member of type `struct time` in `struct date`? If so, you didn't name it, and what you have written doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a member of type `struct time` in `struct date` before you can access the `sec` member of the `struct time` from an object of type `struct date`.

You may elect not to name the nested `struct` but you need a member.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct date
{
   // struct time { ... } time; or
   // struct { ... } time;
   // struct time
   struct
   {
      int sec;
      int min;
      int hrs;
   } time; // Name the member of date.
   int day;
   int month;
   int year;
};

int main(void)
{
   struct date d,*dp=NULL;
   dp=&d;

   dp->time.sec = 10; // Access the sec member
   d.time.min = 20;   // Accces the min member.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested structure is basically a structure within a structure. In your example, `struct time` is a member of `struct date`. 
The logic for accessing member of a structure will remain the same. i.e.the way you access member `day` of `struct date`.

but here you will require to create structure variable for `struct time` in order to access its members.

If you want to access members of nested structure then it will look like,

```
dp->time.sec // dp is a ptr to a struct date
d.time.sec   // d is structure variable of struct date
```

You can check following code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct date
{
        struct time
        {
               int sec;
               int min;
               int hrs;
         }time;
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct date d = {1,2,3,4,5,6}, *dp;

    dp = &d;

    printf(" sec=%d\n min=%d\n hrs=%d\n day=%d\n month=%d\n year=%d\n",dp->time.sec, dp->time.min, dp->time.hrs, dp->day, dp->month, dp->year);


}
```

Output :

```
 sec=1
 min=2
 hrs=3
 day=4
 month=5
 year=6
```